# Dynamically use model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project I create a controller for delete the item from all the blade call the same controller.With passing dynamic id and model name. but showing an error for class not found.
ex: Class 'User' not found.

How can I add use User; code in my controller dynamically.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function deleteItem(Request $req)
    {
        use $req['model'];
        $id = $req['id'];
        $model_name = $req['model'];
        $mdoel_name = $model_name::find($id);
        $mdoel_name->delete();
        sactivity('delete')->performedOn($mdoel_name)->log('');
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an incredibly bad design choice, you really shouldn't use that.

Comment: yes, really bad, you should never do this. Imagine passing some other class name and an id, the user can delete things if he knows the class name and an id. really bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
    $id = $req['id'];
    $model_name = '\\App\\'.$req['model'];
    $model = new $model_name;
    $model_name = $model->find($id);
    $model->delete();
    sactivity('delete')->performedOn($model_name)->log('');
    return "success";
```

Comment: The hell is going on with `$model` and `$mdoel` also, `$mdoel` is undefined, you only have `$mdoel_name`

Answer (score 2):

Store the namespace class name as a string:

```
$Model = Input::get('Model');
$NamespacedModel = '\\Model\\' . $Model;
$Action = $NamespacedModel::find($Id);
```